# Checking if WebBrowser has loaded

Tags: c#, browser

If I have

```
browser.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
```

In a method, how can I check if it has loaded the webpage from within the same method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if it's loaded wherever, do:

```
if(browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
    // It's done!
}
```

However, if you're *waiting* for it to load, handle the `DocumentCompleted` event instead:

```
browser.DocumentCompleted += WhenItsDone;
```

Comment: I am using a static class, is it still possible to listen to an event? Can I do this in the same method as I did the browser.navigate in?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: Yes, and yes.

Comment: Do I add my method to the delegate, or do I wait for the event in the usual method? As in: browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: You add it to the delegate. The "usual method" is added the same way; the designer just does it for you.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper this isn't anywhere near enough re what you need to do to make sure the page has really loaded, check out some of my answers re webbrowser control and how to do proper Is Truely Ready detection, otherwise, i can list all the methods you need to use together, depending on how important your project is. btw, i'm in Melbourne, which city you in? :)

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder: Apparently it is enough, that's why this was marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Erx, you are right. However, I managed to find the methods on my own. Thanks :).

Comment: @thegatekeeper it isn't a matter of finding the methods either, there are things you need to write and develop in addition the the available methods to do it 100% as the built in WB functions aren't enough, unless you are using it for a few sites only and it works for all, then you are safe, but if your users are free to browse any site they want, then you will run into trouble, that's a guarantee unfortunately, feel free to read my answers on the "limitations of webbrowser control" post that I answered.

Comment: The user isnt free to browse, its only sites I want it to access. Dont worry :).

Answer (score 1):

This is Worked For Me:

```
//Waiting For WebBrowser Load

   while(browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) {


   Application.DoEvents();


 }  
      //Do Smth.....
```